# How do you output @ sign in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

In my angular.js project I have the folowing:

{{ myString }}

Now when the value ofmyString is "@", The html output is as follows:

[Object][object]

How can I get round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following example and the "@" is being displayed in the view.  I can't duplicate the issue that you described.  Can you provide more details?

Here's the code I used to display the "@".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
        Hello
        {{myString}}
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
        myScope = $scope; 

        $scope.myString = "@";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I realised I had ng-model="myString" and inside the tag I had {{myString.body}}. I should have tested for other values of the string, I got too distracted by assuming the @ sign was being evaluated as an object. Thanks for your help.